# how to refresh JFrame after after adding java 2d components

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

in this code i added two components to the jframe and also used revalidate and repaint but only one of the components is being viewed. i need a way to refresh the jframe

```
class A extends JPanel{
    int i ,j;
    A(int i,int j){
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawOval(i,j,10,10);
    }
}

public class T2d extends JPanel
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("hi");
        jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        jFrame.add(new A(50,50));
        jFrame.revalidate();//revalidate and repaint doesn't refresh the frame
        jFrame.repaint();//i have read all the past question about this
                        //but none of them solved my problem.

        jFrame.add(new A(1000,100));
        jFrame.revalidate();
        jFrame.repaint();

        jFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so only the last component you added is been updated by the layout manager (`BorderLayout`)

You could try changing the layout manager, maybe `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout`, but since `A` doesn't override the `getPrefferedSize` method, it will be sized to `0x0` by the layout managers anyway.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

It's also kind of pointless calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on a window that hasn't been made visible